# javascript runs on w3schools.com but not on jsfiddle.net?

Tags: javascript

ive used a basic example from w3schools.com to get here:
https://jsfiddle.net/02wu0v49/

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "aaaaaa";
  document.getElementById("fname").value = "bbbbb";
  alert("lala3");
}
```

```html
<body>

  <p>A function is triggered when the user releases a key in the input field. The function outputs the actual key/letter that was released inside the text field.</p>

  Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">

  <p>My name is: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</body>
```

somehow the w3schools version works but it wont do anything on jsfiddle?

and it would be really nice to use [code][/code] or something to format code on stackoverflow...all those indents are terrible.

Comment: i've set Load Type to `No Wrap- in <head>` 
https://jsfiddle.net/BassemMamar/02wu0v49/2/

Comment: That function is not in a `<script>` tag. Is it external? That would be better, anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Change load type to `No wrap in - <body>`

Here is updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/02wu0v49/1/)

Here is [Docs](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#frameworks-and-extensions)

Comment: thank you very much, but why would one need this option for jsfiddle? i mean what does it do to make it work

Comment: @J.Doe , I have given the doc link.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the browser console in JS fiddle it lists the error. The HTML can't find the JS.